# for each row, find value under condition

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, apply

From the example below, for each row, I am trying to get the smallest value among "a" and among "b".

```
set.seed(1234)
M = matrix(sample(20,20), ncol=4)

   M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   10    7    9
[2,]   12    1    5   17
[3,]   11    4   20   16
[4,]   18    8   15   19
[5,]   14    6    2   13

colnames(M) = c("a","b","a","b")
```

So, this is what I am desiring for

```
       "a"  "b"
[1,]    3    9
[2,]    5    1
[3,]   11    4
[4,]   15    8
[5,]    2    6
```

Comment: In addition, if I want to know the column number for the smallest values, how should I do that?

Comment: Regarding the column index, is it the index on the whole dataset or among the 'a' and 'b' columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option by splitting the `data.frame` (converted to `data.frame`) by the column names and get the `pmin` for each row

```
sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(M), colnames(M)), function(x) do.call(pmin, x))
#      a b
#[1,]  3 9
#[2,]  5 1
#[3,] 11 4
#[4,] 15 8
#[5,]  2 6
```

---

If we need the column numbers of the smallest values, then use `max.col`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(as.data.frame(M), colnames(M)), 
  function(x) data.frame(Min = do.call(pmin, x), index = max.col(-x))))
#   a.Min a.index b.Min b.index
#1     3       1     9       2
#2     5       2     1       1
#3    11       1     4       1
#4    15       2     8       1
#5     2       2     6       1
```